# creating textbox in iText 7

Tags: itext7

I am trying to create a textbox using iText 7, and I keep getting nullpointerexception when calling the createText method. I haven't seen anyone discussing this kind of a problem - any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
This is the line of the code which causes the exception:

```
PdfTextFormField textfield = PdfFormField.createText(
    doc,
    new Rectangle(
        params.xfrom, 
        params.yfrom,
        params.xtill,
        params.ytill),
    params.name);
```

Comment: As @Bruno already indicates in a comment to his answer, make your issue reproducible. Using `PdfFormField.createText` with appropriate parameters works just fine as @Bruno illustrates. Thus, your parameters are not appropriate somehow. Some `null` among them? A closed document? Thus, please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet doesn't tell us what `doc` or `params` are about, but I have just tested the example from the [official tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-4-making-pdf-interactive): [c04e02_JobApplication.java](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/examples/chapter-4#1760-c04e02_jobapplication.java), and it executed without any errors, resulting in the following PDF file:

[image]

The `createText()` method of the `PdfTextFormField` class is used like this:

```
PdfTextFormField nameField = PdfTextFormField.createText(doc.getPdfDocument(),
    new Rectangle(99, 753, 425, 15), "name", "");
```

I also tested this variation:

```
PdfTextFormField nameField = PdfTextFormField.createText(doc.getPdfDocument(),
    new Rectangle(99, 753, 425, 15), "name");
```

No exceptions were thrown either.

**Summarized:**

- Either there's a problem with `doc` or `params`, but we can't tell you anything more about that, because you don't show us where you got those parameters,
- Or you aren't using the same iText 7 version as I am using.

Comment: params is an Object - the field name is a String. doc is a PdfDocument object.

Comment: And what does the `NullPointerException` say: is there any chance that `params` is `null`? I mean: I've been helpful. I have tested the method, and I can't reproduce the problem. If you want further help, it's your turn to be helpful. Write me a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that I can execute, and that reproduces the problem. Put yourself in my place: how am I supposed to fix a problem if I can't even reproduce the problem?